# What Fibre Cards can I use with Ubuntu 10.04 LTS Server

Tags: 10.04, server, lts, pcie

What PCIe based fibre cards can I use with Ubuntu? I have been trying to find a native fibre card which works with Ubuntu Server but am unable to. I would really appreciate any help you can point me towards if possible.

Thank you

Comment: Could you be a little more specific concerning the application? I presume
you're trying to attach a SAN. In which case the Emulex or Qlogic HBAs
should suit the purpose. I haven't tested these myself on Ubuntu but
I do know that they're well supported upstream.

Comment: What kind of 'fibre card' are you referring to here? A 1000baseF Ethernet adapter or a Fibre Channel storage adapter?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any personal experience, but this should get you going in the right direction: [Intel Gbit NICs](http://www.intel.com/products/server/adapters/index.htm?iid=embed_portal%20hdprod_server_adapters).  They are controlled with the **e1000e** module.  It supports the Intel PCIe adapters.